# How to remove UIImage Background color and make it transparent?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimage

I wanted to remove UIImage background color and make it transparent...

I tried this but the following code just changing White background color  into Black Color.

```
   UIImage* createColorMaskedImage(UIImage* originalImage){
float maskingColors[6] = {0xEE, 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xFF};
CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(originalImage.CGImage,     maskingColors);
UIImage* maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedImageRef];
CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);
return maskedImage;
}


UIImage *watchImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"watch2.jpg"];
// Mask image
colorMaskImage_ = createColorMaskedImage(watchImage);
//create image view and set its poistion.
UIImageView* maskImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:colorMaskImage_];
CGRect frame = maskImageView.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(80,60);
maskImageView.frame = frame;
maskImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:maskImageView];
[maskImageView release];
```

Comment: @ereilin: This question is about Cocoa Touch, not Cocoa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `watch2.jpg` probably doesn't have alpha values, which would let it have transparent areas.

Comment: Yes Image doesn't have alpha values. How can i make it transparent?Could u please suggest me.

Comment: First off, you need to use a GIF or a PNG and not a JPEG - standard GPEG only stores 24 bits of RGB.  Second, you will need to use an image editing tool like Photoshop to change the background color to be transparent.  Once you are done, when you display this image, you should be able to see through to layers or views underneath, wherever you have a transparent area.

Answer (score 4):

Swift version

```
func makeTransparent(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    guard let rawImage = image.cgImage else { return nil}
    let colorMasking: [CGFloat] = [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    
    if let maskedImage = rawImage.copy(maskingColorComponents: colorMasking),
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: image.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.draw(maskedImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return finalImage
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Amazing, Thanks!!