# How to create a signature scanner and remove white background for transparency?

Tags: swift, swiftui, background

I'm working on a project where I need to create a signature scanner. The basic idea is that a user writes their signature on a sheet of paper with a blue pen, then scans the photo of the signature. The goal is to obtain a PNG image of the signature with a transparent background. The end result must look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/NPW9WLf). User scans image and gets his cleaned signature.

I've been experimenting with Core Image Filters (CIFilters) in Swift to enhance the visibility of the signature and remove the white background. However, I'm facing difficulties in achieving the desired result of replacing the white background with transparency.

I've tried various CIFilters, including "CIColorMatrix," "CIColorInvert," and "CIPhotoEffectMono," but I can't seem to get rid of the white background or make it transparent, so my guess this method is not right for this task.

One of the examples how I've tried to remove background, but it's not working, just returning a black image.

```
    func filterImage() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }

        let beginImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)
        let context = CIContext()

        // Step 1: Create a filter to isolate white color
        let whiteIsolationFilter = CIFilter.colorMatrix()
        whiteIsolationFilter.inputImage = beginImage

        // Step 2: Set the matrix to isolate white color
        let matrix = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0) // Keep non-white colors unchanged
        whiteIsolationFilter.setValue(matrix, forKey: "inputRVector")
        whiteIsolationFilter.setValue(matrix, forKey: "inputGVector")
        whiteIsolationFilter.setValue(matrix, forKey: "inputBVector")

        // Step 3: Apply the filter to the image
        guard let whiteIsolatedImage = whiteIsolationFilter.outputImage else { return }

        // Step 4: Create a mask from the white isolated image
        let whiteMaskFilter = CIFilter.colorMatrix()
        whiteMaskFilter.setValue(whiteIsolatedImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        // Step 5: Set the matrix to create a mask with alpha channel
        let alphaMatrix = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1) // Use alpha channel as a mask
        whiteMaskFilter.setValue(alphaMatrix, forKey: "inputAVector")

        // Composite the original image with a transparent background using the mask
        guard let maskedImage = whiteMaskFilter.outputImage else { return }

        if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(maskedImage, from: maskedImage.extent) {
            let uiimage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
            outputImageMain = uiimage
        }
    }
```

Can anyone provide guidance on how to effectively remove the white background and replace it with transparency and don't remove blue color in this context? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Proving the [reference of work](https://imgur.com/a/NPW9WLf) again. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you find a good solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I am) Gonna post it rn

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an API to do the hard job? You'll save a lot of time and probably delivers a better result. One example could be https://clipdrop.co/apis/docs/remove-background

EDIT

Since you want to do it manually, this is what I came up with:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nonModified: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var modified: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.nonModified.image = UIImage(named: "google-logo")
        self.modified.image = makeTransparent(image: UIImage(named: "google-logo")!)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func makeTransparent(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        guard let rawImage = image.cgImage else { return nil}
        let colorMasking: [CGFloat] = [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
        
        if let maskedImage = rawImage.copy(maskingColorComponents: colorMasking),
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: image.size.height)
            context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            context.draw(maskedImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
            let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return finalImage
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

I've created a simple UI with two image views to check the result and it indeed works:

[image: The upper pic is an unmodified PNG with white background, the 2nd is the pic without background]

I don't take credits for this. I took that function straight from this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63594211/17121575

Comment: That's looking much better, but still there's a lot of noise around the cleaned signature. Any recommendations how to fix it?

Comment: Could you upload a pic somewhere to see hows it looking?

Comment: [Here it is](https://imgur.com/a/ppENYSp)

Comment: And If we upload real life photo, [the result](https://imgur.com/a/72IR1ZK) is even worse

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (nullable UIImage *)filteredImage:(UIImage *)srcImage
                   withRedValue:(NSInteger)redValue
                 greenValue:(NSInteger)greenValue
                  blueValue:(NSInteger)blueValue
                    opacity:(CGFloat)opacity{
    
    if (!srcImage) {
        // Handle the case where the input image is nil
        return nil;
    }

    cv::Mat srcImageMat;
    cv::Mat grayImageMat;
    cv::Mat thresholdedMat;
    cv::Mat rgbaMat; // To store the result with transparency
    
    // Convert from UIImage to cv::Mat
    UIImageToMat(srcImage, srcImageMat);
    
    // Convert the color space from RGB to Gray
    cv::cvtColor(srcImageMat, grayImageMat, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    
    // Apply image thresholding (adjust the threshold value as needed)
    cv::threshold(grayImageMat, thresholdedMat, 140, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    
    // Convert to 4-channel RGBA image
    cv::cvtColor(srcImageMat, rgbaMat, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

    // Set the alpha channel to be the inverse of the thresholded image
    for (int i = 0; i < rgbaMat.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rgbaMat.cols; j++) {
            if (thresholdedMat.at<uchar>(i, j) == 255) {
                rgbaMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i, j)[3] = 0; // Set alpha to 0 for white pixels
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rgbaMat.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rgbaMat.cols; j++) {
            if (thresholdedMat.at<uchar>(i, j) == 0) {
                // If the pixel is not white in the thresholded image (alpha is 255), change the color here
                // For example, let's set the color to red (R=255, G=0, B=0)
                rgbaMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i, j)[0] = redValue; // Red
                rgbaMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i, j)[1] = greenValue;   // Green
                rgbaMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i, j)[2] = blueValue;   // Blue
                rgbaMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i, j)[3] = opacity;
            }
        }
    }

    // Convert from cv::Mat to UIImage
    UIImage *combinedImage = MatToUIImage(rgbaMat);
    
    return combinedImage;
}
```

Comment: You are using opencv, right?

Comment: Yep, I am using It in here.